Can I optimize UPDATE statements using EXPLAIN?
I have a few UPDATE calls on my production system that are running slow and I've been instructed to try and optimize them. I'm reading into how to understand EXPLAIN with (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) as well to get more information and I'm trying to figure out why this one plan node is taking so long. I have a feeling that it might be dude to the number of records that are getting updated but I wonder if someone with more experience looking at EXPLAIN output might be able to shed some light on this mystery?
Here is the UPDATE statement that is showing up in my metrics:
-- $1 and $2 are variables set in a Rails application
UPDATE "redacted_table_name"
   SET "some_fk_id" = $1
 WHERE "redacted_table_name"."some_fk_id" = $2

For context, this table has over 280 million records. I wanted to try and do a full analysis on this table so I had the database cloned and ran a "safe" EXPLAIN (ANYALYZE, BUFFERS) which runs an actual update and sure enough it took quite some time to complete:
-- Do an actual UPDATE w/o changing any data
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)
UPDATE "redacted_table_name"
   SET "some_fk_id" = 1
 WHERE "redacted_table_name"."some_fk_id" = 1

QUERY PLAN:

Update on redacted_table_name  (cost=669.64..108899.13 rows=0 width=0) (actual time=104067.491..104067.492 rows=0 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=3329124 read=290028 dirtied=276605 written=906
  I/O Timings: shared read=90426.849 write=26.727
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on redacted_table_name  (cost=669.64..108899.13 rows=30073 width=10) (actual time=213.507..14936.244 rows=137766 loops=1)
        Recheck Cond: (some_fk_id = 1)
        Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 5904106
        Heap Blocks: exact=39787 lossy=38580
        Buffers: shared hit=411 read=78433 dirtied=10
        I/O Timings: shared read=14094.250
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_redacted_table_name_on_some_fk_id  (cost=0.00..662.12 rows=30073 width=0) (actual time=206.434..206.434 rows=137766 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (some_fk_id = 1)
              Buffers: shared read=477
              I/O Timings: shared read=193.942
Planning Time: 0.074 ms
Execution Time: 104067.523 ms

As you can see, I have an INDEX already on "redacted_table_name"."some_fk_id" which PG is taking advantage of but why is it doing a Bitmap Head Scan after the fact? It doesn't seem to be using the INDEX that its child node is using. Why is it taking so long there?
Here is a similar update on the some_fk_id column that has the most records in the table (3 million records and the worst case scenario):
Update on redacted_table_name  (cost=0.00..5344540.00 rows=0 width=0) (actual time=436965.067..436965.068 rows=0 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=139949860 read=4964122 dirtied=4521138 written=1928290
  I/O Timings: shared read=176626.661 write=8909.815
  ->  Seq Scan on redacted_table_name  (cost=0.00..5344540.00 rows=3890845 width=10) (actual time=0.026..36374.777 rows=3617975 loops=1)
        Filter: (some_fk_id = 93330)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 278327308
        Buffers: shared hit=207516 read=1612708 dirtied=52 written=420751
        I/O Timings: shared read=17983.171 write=2653.138
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=1
Planning Time: 0.078 ms
Execution Time: 436965.106 ms

The Seq Scan on redacted_table_name indicates to me that the index wasn't even used with this UPDATE. So what gives?
UPDATE:
Both on my prod and my cloned prod the work_mem is 4MB and on prod shared_buffers is 8047248kB but on the cloned prod that I ran these on the shared_buffers was 3983192kB. The prod clone was shutdown so I wasn't able to get the effective_cache_size but prod has 7966384kB for that setting.
UPDATE: #2
Below is the CREATE TABLE script along with all of the constraints and indexes that are on the table:
-- This table simply has a PK and four foreign keys
-- that reference other tables in the database.
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.redacted_table_name
(
    id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('redacted_table_name_id_seq'::regclass),
    fk_table_3_id bigint,

    -- to stay with example above this is the key/column
    -- that's getting updated.
    some_fk_id bigint,
    fk_table_4_id bigint,
    fk_table_2_id bigint,
    fk_table_1_id bigint,
    CONSTRAINT redacted_table_name_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_rails_3fc9a63917 FOREIGN KEY (fk_table_4_id)
        REFERENCES public.fk_table_4 (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT fk_rails_4e272bcb96 FOREIGN KEY (fk_table_1_id)
        REFERENCES public.fk_table_1 (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT fk_rails_9ba08049bc FOREIGN KEY (some_fk_id)
        REFERENCES public.some_fk_table (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT fk_rails_d6e3c90d4d FOREIGN KEY (fk_table_3_id)
        REFERENCES public.fk_table_3 (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT fk_rails_f79e2fb3ae FOREIGN KEY (fk_table_2_id)
        REFERENCES public.fk_table_2 (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS public.redacted_table_name
    OWNER to pg_user;

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS index_redacted_table_name_on_fk_table_4_id
    ON public.redacted_table_name USING btree
    (fk_table_4_id ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS index_redacted_table_name_on_some_fk_id
    ON public.redacted_table_name USING btree
    (some_fk_id ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS index_redacted_table_name_on_fk_table_1_id
    ON public.redacted_table_name USING btree
    (fk_table_1_id ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS index_redacted_table_name_on_fk_table_2_id
    ON public.redacted_table_name USING btree
    (fk_table_2_id ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS index_redacted_table_name_on_fk_table_3_id
    ON public.redacted_table_name USING btree
    (fk_table_3_id ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS index_redacted_table_name_on_fk_table_3_id_and_some_fk_id
    ON public.redacted_table_name USING btree
    (fk_table_3_id ASC NULLS LAST, some_fk_id ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS unique_on_fk_table_3_fk_table_4
    ON public.redacted_table_name USING btree
    (fk_table_3_id ASC NULLS LAST, some_fk_id ASC NULLS LAST, fk_table_1_id ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

TL;DR
Is this just a slow SQL statement due to the number of rows it has to update or can I optimize this table somehow? If I'm not providing enough information, please let me know what you need and I'll provide it.
Thanks again for any help!

What's your shared_buffers and work_mem size?

Great question: Both on my prod and my cloned prod the work_mem is 4MB and on prod shared_buffers is 8047248kB but on the cloned prod that I ran these on the shared_buffers was 3983192kB.

Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Please put relevant info into the question - use comments to let people know you have responded.

@aarona I see a lot of lossy blocks in your first query which may due to small work_mem. You may try increase it in cloned box. Is it shared_buffers1/4th of your server's memory size?How the effective_cache_size set? Additionally  I suggest you try a VACUUM ANALYZE on your cloned machine for this table if you haven't tried yet.

@Vérace thanks and done!

@goodfella thanks for your help, I will try these things. The DB is on AWS if that matters. I'll have to talk with someone from work that has access to that information and get back to you. I optimized a bunch of other queries so stakeholders are pretty happy currently and might not have me complete this task at the moment. I updated my post with more information.

A bitmap index scan gives you a bitmap.  You can't do anything with a bitmap, other than a bitmap heap scan (and a few Boolean operations, which in turn just give you bitmaps which in turn need a bitmap heap scan to do anything with.)
You also seemed confused by the seq scan in one case.  Once the expected number of effected rows is large enough as a portion of the table, using an index to find them becomes counter productive and a seq scan is better.  It is not obvious that the planner made the correct decision there, but it is also not obvious it made the wrong one.
In any event, the bitmap heap scan only takes 1/7 of the time.  Most of the time is spend doing the actual update.  I suspect most of that is due to maintaining the indexes. With 8 indexes to be maintained, it is not surprising that this is a lot of work.  I notice that two of your indexes have columns lists which are prefixes of another index, so those can almost surely be dropped without consequence, and then they won't need to be maintained anymore.
Index maintenance is also not needed on Heap-Only-Tuple updates, so you could try to encourage those by lowering the fill factor.  But this is probably pointless, because HOT updates are only possible when no indexed column changes. That is the case in your query only because you set the value back to the same thing it already was (and the HOT machinery detects this fact), but I assume such dummy updates are not going to be the case generally and so trying this seems like a lost cause.  Also note that if you are not doing dummy updates, then you also need to verify the foreign key constraint is still maintained which will add extra work.
Pretty much all of the time is going to reading buffers from disk, presumably index buffers in order to do the maintenance on them.  So reducing the number of indexes in need of maintenance can reduce this time, but so can just making the IO faster.  You could do that by getting faster disks, or by increasing disk caching via more memory, or maybe by partitioning such that rows being updated at the same time are likely in the same partition.
PostgreSQL does not (yet) have a way to issue IO reads asynchronously for doing index maintenance on btree indexes.  If you are limited by IO latency but have plenty of throughput capacity to spare, you could get better performance by having multiple update statements (of non-overlapping rows) running at the same time.

@jjames thanks for the help. I updated my post with a CREATE TABLE script complete with FKs and other indexes.

There could be lock waits as well, right?

@LaurenzAlbe He tested on a cloned server, so I doubt there would be conflicting concurrent activity going on for the shown executions.

@jjanes you're correct. Nothing else was connecting to it by my own PGAdmin client instance.
I just had a thought: Because this update statement is updating a foreign key (some_fk_id is a FK for some_fk_table.id as my CREATE TABLE statement states) from one value to another, does it have to check for each update that the new value exists as an id on some_fk_table? Would it check once or for each update?

@aarona If the update changes the value from its old one, then it checks the constraint for every row being updated.  This will be reported in the plan under "Trigger for constraint ..." at the end of the plan, but this line is suppressed in your show plan because your update didn't actually change the value.

@jjanes PG Docs for EXPLAIN tells me that I can do an EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) on an update statement within a BEGIN TRANSACTION that ROLLBACKs at the end and get the EXPLAIN output that way but when I do this, I think the EXPLAIN output gets suppressed by the last ROLLBACK statement so it just says "success" etc. If I can figure out how to get that explain plan to show up in PGAdmin4 then I can actually update the values and see that output. This db clone has been shutdown for now so it might be a while before I come back to this. Giving you a +1 at least because of your help.
